# Kafka Consumer does not start or subscribe as no output in console

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am newbie in Kafka,have a small program to run the KAfka consumer and i am posting messages to Kafka using Kafka tool.
I am able to get/read messages from kafka when i configure the setup in windows 7 but it does not work in windows10.

this is my code:

```
public class Sample`Consumer {
public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SampleConsumer.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9999");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "colly");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");

        KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(config);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("tnd_test_poc"));

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("inside the while loop");
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                logger.info("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value:" + record.value());
                logger.info("Partition:" + record.partition() + ",Offset:" + record.offset());
                System.out.println("display record" + records);
            }
        }
    }catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Exception while consuming messages from kafka", t);
        Assert.fail("Exception while consuming messages from kafka");
    }
}
```

}

I can read the messages in windows7 but same does not work in windows10.
I do not get any error/warning/exception in console output, it just runs and keeps on running.
Can you please advise for this issue?
I got know this can be due to no connection happening due to security credentials and hence no output. And second thing kafka client dependency not compatible.
Everything works in Windows7 though.
I am using below dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Please assist.

Comment: 1) You dont need Zookeeper properties 2) Did you use the same group id on each run?

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the exact same code, then the group-id offsets were committed, and unless you send new data to the topic, your consumer group resumes from the end of the topic, so you'd see no current messages.